# Two different shadows on a Rectangle in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

Intention is to have a darker shadow on the top and left sides of the rectangle, and lighter shadow on bottom and right sides of the same rectangle.

This is what I have tried:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.12

Rectangle
{
    width: 150
    height: 150

    Rectangle
    {
        id: rect
        color: "#292a38"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 192
        height: 42
        radius: 6
    }

    DropShadow
    {
        anchors.fill: rect
        horizontalOffset: 5
        verticalOffset: 5
        radius: 5
        samples: 6
        color: "#1c1c26"
    }

    DropShadow
    {
        anchors.fill: rect
        horizontalOffset: -5
        verticalOffset: -5
        radius: 5
        samples: 6
        color: "#343848"
    }

    InnerShadow
    {
        anchors.fill: rect
        radius: 8
        samples: 16
        horizontalOffset: 10
        verticalOffset: 10
        color: "#1a1b2f"
    }
}
```

It results in the following shape:

[image]

As you can see this is not satisfactory. Please guide.

Comment: What the result you would be satisfied with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to set the `source` property on your effects.

```
    DropShadow
    {
        anchors.fill: rect
        horizontalOffset: 5
        verticalOffset: 5
        radius: 5
        samples: 6
        color: "#1c1c26"
        source: rect   // This is needed
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped. Also I removed the InnerShadow. That made it neater.